# UE4-Changing movement speed depending on the direction of movement

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a third person character. I use controller desired rotation for rotating character with the mouse as in PUBG etc. How can I change max walk speed when I go forward? For example, when I walk forward my speed must be 500 but when I walk right or backward my speed must be 250. How to detect this? I certainly can add if-s on input axis events but my game is multiplayer and this will reduce performance if I check and change speed every tick. Нow to solve it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a solution for Blueprints, although I can't be certain it's appropriate in your case.

The key is to add movement input to the forward vector of your player character. See the screenshot below.

[image: Blueprint for direction-dependent movement speed]

The *AxisValue* output from the *MoveForward* input event is +1 when you press forward and -1 when you press back.

If your walk speed is 500 then the upper *AddMovementInput* adds 500 movement, multiplied by 1, in the direction the player is facing.

The lower one adds 500 movement, multiplied by -1 multipled by 0.5, which will make you go backward (technically, forward with a negative value) at half speed.

You can apply the same logic to the *MoveRight* input.

PS If you're using an analogue controller, I assume *AxisValue* will be in the range -1 to 1, but that doesn't change the logic above.

Comment: Thank you very much!